# Cant attach news items to user in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

This is a follow-up post to [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63683908/how-to-display-only-news-items-that-havent-been-seen-by-a-user/63684045?noredirect=1#comment112614746_63684045)

I am trying to attach news items to users via a pivot table so that I can display each users news items to them after they log in. The idea being that when a user has seen an item they can check a box to detach that item and not see it again.

My news items seem to be saving, but nothing is saved in the pivot table to associate them with users. Ideally, when a news item is saved, it should be attached to all users.

**Migrations**

**create_news_table**

```
class CreateNewsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->boolean('sticky');
            $table->boolean('draft');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**create_news_user_pivot_table**

```
class CreateNewsUserPivotTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('news_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('news_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('news_id')->references('id')->on('news')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Models**

**News.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\News;

class News extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'news';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'sticky', 'draft',];

    public function users() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\News')->withPivot('user_id', 'news_id');
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable {

        use Notifiable;
        use SoftDeletes;


        //protected $table = "users";
        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'email',
            'password',
            'profilePic',
            'role',
            'verify',
            'first_time_login',
            'changedPasswordDate',
            'needToChangePassword',
            'userRoles'
        ];

        protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token',
        ];

        public function news() {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\News')->withPivot('user_id', 'news_id');
        }
}
```

**NewsUser.php** (not even sure I need a model for the pivot table)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class NewsUser extends Model {

    protected $table = 'news_user';
    protected $fillable = ["user_id", "news_id"];
}
```

**Relevant function from controller**

```
public function saveNews(Request $request) {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $news = new News;
        $news->title = $request->title;
        $news->body = $request->body;
        $news->sticky = $request->sticky;
        $news->draft = $request->draft;
        $news->save();
        $user->news()->attach($news->id);
    }
```

I realise that this last function is only attempting to add the news post to the current user, but if I solve this, then I can figure out how to attach the news item to all users later. Something like this I guess:

```
$users = \App\User::all()

foreach $users as $user {
    $user->news()->attach($news->id);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any actual error messages? If not, is your app in debug-mode?

Comment: App is in debug mode, but I'm not getting the usual laravel debug page with an error.

Answer (score 0):

im guessing here `return $this->belongsToMany('App\News')->withPivot('user_id', 'news_id');`

maybe try `return $this->belongsToMany('App\News', 'news_user', 'user_id', 'news_id');` in User model and vice-versa in News Model as `belongsToMany()` foreign keys will present, `withPivot()` adds extra attributes but you using its foreign as it is extra attributes

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of problems I found once I was looking at all the code in one place.

News.php

```
public function users()
```

should have been

```
public function user()
```

and it was also returning wrong, 'App\News' should be 'App\User'

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\News')->withPivot('user_id', 'news_id');
```

should have been

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'news_user', 'news_id');
```

and then in my controller, to attach a news item to all users after it is saved

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $news->user()->attach($user->id);
}
```